# ExtJS 3.4 - have an issue with loading data into a datastore and then displaying on a flex grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, datastore

I am a novice at best so much of this I have pieced together by trial and error.  I'm sure there are a lot of issues and probably better ways of accomplishing what I am trying to do.  Just need to figure out the data store issue if possible.

Here is a link to the current working code base:
http://www.keystone-360.com/Beta beta page

And here is the zip file containing all of html/js/css files:
http://www.keystone-360.com/Beta/beta.zip beta.zip

Comment: Sorry - should have been a little more clear on where the issue is.  Once a drawing is clicked on (left panel) and an object is clicked on (center panel) then the properties (photos, notes, documents, etc.) of that object come up in right panel.  I have the photos populating correctly but the notes and documents are where I'm trying to use a datastore with a flexgrid to display links to each of the files.  Hopefully this better explains the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is where model view controller comes into play.  The fields and grids on the right panel will bind to the datastores.  Stores are like tables in a database.  They contain models which are like records.

The kitchen sink has a large section on data binding.  The binding is the same more or less across the modern and classic tool kits.
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#data-binding

https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.0/examples/classic/writer/writer-jsonp.html